# Is it possible to let the script tag applies to only a certain div

Tags: jquery, html

there is a question I would like to ask.
I have 2 jquery codes that helps to filter rows of a table, using the quicksearch of the javascript library.

Sample code is like

```
$('#searchtextbox').quicksearch('#tableId tbody tr');
```

Now I have 2 tables in the same page. I want to let searchtextbox1 search table 1
searchtextbox2 search table 2

Now here is the most crucial criteria:
The two tables HAVE the same id

Is it possible to wrap this jquery code in a script tag inside the table so that it only filters the particular table? I can change the jquery code, the searchtextboxId and everything else EXCEPT the tableID.. anyone knows how can I do this?

Comment: **ID should always be unique**

Comment: ID must be unique, you can differenciate tables by using another class or another html attribute

Comment: Just name them `table1` and `table2`. Then, do `$('#searchtextbox1`).quicksearch('#table1'); $('#searchtextbox2`).quicksearch('#table2');`. What is the problem? :)

Comment: You're falling vitctim to the XY problem: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem

You *think* you need to work around the fact you have two identical IDs, when in fact it's the matching IDs that is the very problem. And it's (potentially) a big problem, get rid of one, and use classes instead.